# prevent django session from expiring

Tags: django

I have a site where once a user logs in I would like them to never get logged out. I have set SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = sys.maxint but still, after some amount of time (I don't know exactly how long, but it's around 12 hours) the users get a login page. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 315360000 # 10 years
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

whenever a new request is made the session will reset the age also.

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: where should we add this? settings.py?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE, the default value is set to two weeks. If the high value you set is not persisting the cookie longer, I would guess that the issue is elsewhere.

How do you set the cookie? If you are using the `HttpResponse.set_cookie()` method I would set the max_age parameter to be some distant time, using the syntax described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie

Comment: I do not set the cookie anywhere in the app.

Comment: Ah, I see. you could use this middleware that updates sessions periodically. No idea how effective it is: https://github.com/IlyaSemenov/django-everlasting-sessions